# Technique to integrate Postgresql10 tables in EF

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

Is there any method to sync Postgresql tables into c# (visual studio) with Entity Framework auto generated classes?
I had no luck by doing that by myself writing the classes corresponding to the tables, when I update a table in the db no change appears in my classes.

I searched all  , but nothing seems not to work with postgres

Comment: I changed my question, is it ok now?

Comment: It's worse now. The question doesn't explain what you tried or what the problem was. Not even which EF provider you used, or which EF version. If you google for `Entity Framework PostgreSQL` you'll get a *lot* of results

Comment: The provider almost everyone uses is NpgSQL. [The Getting Started doc](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/) shows how to reverse engineer an existing database and generate classes with